# Javascript Stuck on Error Alert for Validation Code unless Page is Reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that I have a bunch of different selections that someone makes on the page visually, and as the selections get made or get changed it updates the data in attributes on the "Save to Favorite" button. Everything works great, including the AJAX post function to the database, but when I add validation code into it, if there is an error it gets stuck on the error, even after I fix it. I have to reload the page, to clear the error in order to make it work.

Here is the php for the button:

```
<div id="saveFavoriteSection">
    <div id="">Save Favorite As: <input type="text" id="groupName"></div>
    <div id="addFavButton"><a data-entityid="" data-presid="" data-refid="" data-ref2id="" data-aptid="" data-insid="" data-offerid="" data-offer2id="" data-instxtid="" data-brgid="">Add to Favorites Button</a></div>
</div>
```

My Validation code in the JS is as follows:

```
function favButton(e){
e.preventDefault();

//Assign Variables
var pres_id = $(this).data('presid');
var ref_id = $(this).data('refid');
var ref2_id = $(this).data('ref2id');
var apt_id = $(this).data('aptid');
var ins_id = $(this).data('insid');
var offer_id = $(this).data('offerid');
var offer2_id = $(this).data('offer2id');
var ins_txt_id = $(this).data('instxtid');
var brg_id = $(this).data('brgid');
var entity_id = $(this).data('entityid');

if(pres_id == ""){
    alert('Please Choose a Presentation Card Design');
}else if(ref_id == ""){
    alert('Please Choose a Referral Card Design');
}else if(apt_id == ""){
    if($('input[name=appointmentOn]:checked').val() == 'yes'){
        alert('Please Choose an Appointment Sleeve Design');
    }
}else if(brg_id == ""){
    if($('input[name=burgopakOn]:checked').val() == 'yes'){
        alert('Please Choose a MagicPak Design');
    }
}else if(offer_id == ""){
    alert('Please Choose an Offer for the Outside Referral Card');
}else if(offer2_id == ""){
    if($('input[name=referralInsideOn]:checked').val() == 'yes'){
        alert('Please Choose an Offer for the Inside Referral Card');
    }
}else if(ins_txt_id == ""){
    alert('Please Choose Copy for the Insert');
}else if(group_id == ""){
    alert('Please Enter a Favorite Name');
}else{
    alert('Successfully done dude!');
    //Run executable code and POST here
}
}
```

Here is the listening function to call the button function:

```
$('#addFavButton').delegate('a', 'click', favButton);
```

I have tested the code by filling out each item and each alert triggers when it is supposed to correctly. So, for example, if I purposefully leave out the "Presentation Card ID", an alert will come up that says 'Please Choose a Presentation Card Design', which is correct. So I then choose a design (without reloading the page) and press the button again, it gives me the same error, even though I have fixed there error on the page.

It is like it gets stuck at the point of the first error and doesn't try to run the code from the beginning. If I reload the page and choose a presentation card design and try it again it works fine, but I can't have people coming to this site reloading the page.

Is there something I am missing on the validation to clear the error and run the function again from the beginning without reloading the page?

Comment: `if(pres_id) == ""){` You have an extra closing parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry, not like that in code, fixed the page post.

Comment: How are the different variables being set (like "pres_id", "ref_id"...etc) that you use to validate? I would assume the value isn't being updated on change.

Comment: They are being set like: var pres_id = $(this).data('presid'); the favButton a is the $(this) in this case. These are being set where it says //Assign Variables above.

Comment: The values are being updated under the favButton(i.e data-presid="34") on change, but when I press the button again, it is not pulling or reading the data and the function still sees it as blank. So it's like it's not pulling the data again or something. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: You probably need to make sure the data is being updated. The problem is most likely somewhere in the function that updates the data on change of the element.

Comment: As stated above values are being updated on page. Here is a link so you can see what I am talking about: [package-designer](https://viva-cards.com/products/package-designer-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assigning the variables incorrectly. While is works in most cases it did not allow me to pull the data again after running a validation check for some reason. I changed them to be attr('data-presid'), instead of data('presid'). So, by changing the variables to the following it works fine now:

```
var pres_id = $(this).attr('data-presid');
var ref_id = $(this).attr('data-refid');
var ref2_id = $(this).attr('data-ref2id');
var apt_id = $(this).attr('data-aptid');
var ins_id = $(this).attr('data-insid');
var offer_id = $(this).attr('data-offerid');
var offer2_id = $(this).attr('data-offer2id');
var ins_txt_id = $(this).attr('data-instxtid');
var brg_id = $(this).attr('data-brgid');
var entity_id = $(this).attr('data-entityid');
```